# How exactly theᴅᴀᴏ reentrancy hack was performed without having weiGiven>0 nor IsAllowed(WithdrawAddress)?

Tags: security, the-dao, reentrant-attacks

The well known ᴅᴀᴏ hack didn’t affect ether balances of theᴅᴀᴏ but balances of [rewardAccount](https://etherscan.io/address/0xd2e16a20dd7b1ae54fb0312209784478d069c7b0).

That’s why I’m talking about the hack version which affected [contract balances of theᴅᴀᴏ itself](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf27e09632918e71eda39ac92628616c2bc5c36d64de131b63f68569cc9403654).

With the help [blockchair](https://blockchair.com/ethereum/calls?q=transaction_id(2130761000000),value_usd(0.01..)&s=index(asc)#), I could get the input data being used, so I know it’also about `SplitDao`, but how the hacker could both set the SpliData on it’s ᴅᴀᴏ proposal and `_recipient` inside the targeted reentrency contract ?
By looking at the code, this set of conditions seems mutually exclusive to me.

Comment: **Not a Duplicate ! I’m talking about an other version of the hack : not the original one.**